# Unreal control possession issue

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I created a Third Person project in Unreal engine. Everything was working fine for a while. Meaning, I was able to control the player when I previewed the game (play). Due to something I probably did, at one point I could no longer control the player in the preview mode. Instead, it seems that I am controlling the default player -- sort of a camera that hangs up in the sky. I checked all the settings Including the "Default Pawn Class" in the project settings, as well as in the world settings.

Not sure what I did wrong or what settings do I need to change. I would love to get some help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you running simulate instead of play?

Comment: I was running the simulate mode. I probably chose that by mistake. I changed it back and now everything seems to be working just fine. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, I was running in the simulate mode. I change back to the "Selected Viewport" mode and everything is back to normal.